# Transform list of dictionary with lists of dictionary to dataframe in an optimal way - yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I'm trying to download data with yahoo finance module for Income Statement and transform into flat data frame.   I have it working with code below.   But I wondered if there was a better way for me to build data frame for 22 columns of figures for multiple tickers/periods.  In the code below I've referenced just a small number of keys (items) using the the key name and then appending data to lists before zipping them up at the end of the iteration.

What I would prefer would to be loop through lists/dicts and use the keys for the column name without having to literal specify each column.  This is tricky as this data has many layers Ticker (Dict)-> Period (List) -> Item (Dict).   I've tried using the keys/value in a for loop but struggling to get that working due to lists of dicts.   Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import datetime as dt

all_tickers = ["AAPL","MSFT","AMZN"]
researchDevelopment =[]
incomeBeforeTax = []
p_ticket = []
period = []


for ticker in all_tickers:
    yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
    income_statement_qt = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('quarterly', 'income', reformat=True)
    i = income_statement_qt.get('incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly')
    d = i[ticker]
    
    for i in range(len(d)):
        p = d[i]
        for x in p:
            period.append(x)
            researchDevelopment.append(p[x]['researchDevelopment'])
            incomeBeforeTax.append(p[x]['incomeBeforeTax'])
            p_ticket.append(ticker)

d = list(zip(p_ticket, period, researchDevelopment, incomeBeforeTax ))
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Ticket','Period','ResearchDevelopment','IncomeBeforeTax'])

print(df)
```

-------------------------
Sample Data from API
-------------------------

    {'incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly': {'MSFT': [{'2020-12-31': {'researchDevelopment': 4899000000, 'effectOfAccountingCharges': None, 'incomeBeforeTax': 18337000000, 'minorityInterest': None, 'netIncome': 15463000000, 'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 6086000000, 'grossProfit': 28882000000, 'ebit': 17897000000, 'operatingIncome': 17897000000, 'otherOperatingExpenses': None, 'interestExpense': -568000000, 'extraordinaryItems': None, 'nonRecurring': None, 'otherItems': None, 'incomeTaxExpense': 2874000000, 'totalRevenue': 43076000000, 'totalOperatingExpenses': 25179000000, 'costOfRevenue': 14194000000, 'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': 440000000, 'discontinuedOperations': None, 'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': 15463000000, 'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': 15463000000}}, {'2020-09-30': {'researchDevelopment': 4926000000, 'effectOfAccountingCharges': None, 'incomeBeforeTax': 16124000000, 'minorityInterest': None, 'netIncome': 13893000000, 'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 5350000000, 'grossProfit': 26152000000, 'ebit': 15876000000, 'operatingIncome': 15876000000, 'otherOperatingExpenses': None, 'interestExpense': -585000000, 'extraordinaryItems': None, 'nonRecurring': None, 'otherItems': None, 'incomeTaxExpense': 2231000000, 'totalRevenue': 37154000000, 'totalOperatingExpenses': 21278000000, 'costOfRevenue': 11002000000, 'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': 248000000, 'discontinuedOperations': None, 'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': 13893000000, 'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': 13893000000}}, {'2020-06-30': {'researchDevelopment': 5214000000, 'effectOfAccountingCharges': None, 'incomeBeforeTax': 13422000000, 'minorityInterest': None, 'netIncome': 11202000000, 'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 7073000000, 'grossProfit': 25694000000, 'ebit': 13407000000, 'operatingIncome': 13407000000, 'otherOperatingExpenses': None, 'interestExpense': -684000000, 'extraordinaryItems': None, 'nonRecurring': None, 'otherItems': None, 'incomeTaxExpense': 2220000000, 'totalRevenue': 38033000000, 'totalOperatingExpenses': 24626000000, 'costOfRevenue': 12339000000, 'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': 15000000, 'discontinuedOperations': None, 'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': 11202000000, 'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': 11202000000}}, {'2020-03-31': {'researchDevelopment': 4887000000, 'effectOfAccountingCharges': None, 'incomeBeforeTax': 12843000000, 'minorityInterest': None, 'netIncome': 10752000000, 'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 6184000000, 'grossProfit': 24046000000, 'ebit': 12975000000, 'operatingIncome': 12975000000, 'otherOperatingExpenses': None, 'interestExpense': -615000000, 'extraordinaryItems': None, 'nonRecurring': None, 'otherItems': None, 'incomeTaxExpense': 2091000000, 'totalRevenue': 35021000000, 'totalOperatingExpenses': 22046000000, 'costOfRevenue': 10975000000, 'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': -132000000, 'discontinuedOperations': None, 'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': 10752000000, 'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': 10752000000}}]}}

Comment: Seeing the structure for `income_statement_qt` is impossible without running your code. Instead, show a sample of `income_statement_qt` as downloaded. Also provide what `all_tickers` contains; without it, it's impossible to even run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the right structure, you don't need any list(zip(...)), you must learn to use dictionaries and not only lists.
And you've got to know that a DataFrame, is exactly like a dictionary that looks like :

```py
dict_df = {
    'column0' : {
        'index0' : 'value0',   
        'index1' : 'value1',  
        # etc
    },
    'column1' : {
        'index0' : 'value0',   
        'index1' : 'value1',  
        # etc
    },
    # etc
}
```

Then at the end, simple :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)
```

At the same time, it is very versatile and here you don't have a meaningful index (or have you ?), so you can just use a dict of lists instead of a dict of dicts.

So to start with, create the skeleton of the dictionary

```py
LIST_COLUMNS = ['Ticket','Period','ResearchDevelopment','IncomeBeforeTax']
df_dict = {col: [] for col in LIST_COLUMNS}
```

Then in your loop(s?), you fill directly the dictionary.

Bet here you should also use list comprehensions, here the two nested loops are useless...

```py
for ticker in all_tickers:
    ...

    df_dict['period'] += [x for p in d for x in p]
    df_dict['researchDevelopment'] += [p[x]['researchDevelopment'] for p in d for x in p]
    # etc
```